# Gradle assembleDebug of an Android project fails with aapt error

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

I'm trying to establish a gradle build for an Android library project, but currently the build fails during processDebugRes with an aapt error:

```
:packageDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:packageDebugRes UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugRes
ERROR: Unknown option '--output-text-symbols'
Android Asset Packaging Tool

Usage:
 aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
   List contents of Zip-compatible archive.

(...)

:processDebugRes FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The build.gradle is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.1' }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {

    target = 'android-16'

    defaultConfig {

        versionCode = 16
        versionName = "1.0"
        minSdkVersion = 8
    }
}
```

BTW, the aapt version is 0.2.

I'm new to the whole Gradle thing, so thanks in advance for any pointers on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the problem on my own - I was using revision 14 of the Android SDK platform tools, not the preview of revision 15, which is required according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/using-the-new-build-system.